# Get all console content into a file

Tags: ios, logging

Im trying to get all console logs into a file.

I found posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071992/how-to-programmatically-get-the-log-messages-in-an-ios-app). I have been testing this: no content displayed with NSLog (its displayed with print) but no data is written into the file, neither the NSLog nor the print ones.

When the app closes i close the file.

I did as follows:

```
var file: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>?

func logAll() {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let filename = "/\(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).log"
    let logFilePath = paths[0].appending(filename)
    file = freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: .ascii), "a+", stderr)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    logAll()
    /// rest of the code
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let file = file {
        fclose(file)
    }
}
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: _What am i missing here?_ For one thing,`applicationWillTerminate` will never be called, so you never close the file.

Comment: @matt im testing in an old app, its being called

Comment: Ah, so that's why you can't use OSLog?

Comment: @matt my target is also get what third party libraries would print into the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i have this.

There are 3 std files: `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`

As i was just trying with prints i didnt see it, but regular prints are stored in `stdout` file. Later, trying in a project with more libraries, it seems (firebase, for example) logs are stored in `stderr`.

So, instead of opening just one file i have just to open the 3 files in order to get all logs.

The only con by now is that i dont have a way to get the correct order